# CANBUS, understanding if a tranceivers is 3V compatible or not

Tags: can

I am looking for a way to tell if a CANBUS tranceiver chip I have is 3V-5V IO compatible or 5V-only.
There are many situation were this applies, like non-readable chip markings and "alternative" chip codes from "alternative" vendor (quotes to include "non-original" scenario).

[TJA1051 datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/TJA1051.pdf) distinguish between 3.3V (IO) compatible silicon, like TJA1051T/3, and 5V-only compatible ones, as TJA1051T/E.
[Same applies](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATA6560-ATA6561-High-Speed-CAN-Transceiver-DS20005991A.pdf) for ATA6561, which is 3V IO compatible, and ATA6560 which is not.
This probably stands for other tranceivers out there, too.

These tranceivers, sharing the same form factors and pinouts, differentiates 3V-5V and 5V-only IO compatible versions through VIO pin.

For TJA1051, section "VIO supply pin" states: "For versions of the TJA1051 without a VIO pin, the VIO input is internally connected to VCC."

For ATA656x datasheet says:

```
Note 1: Pin 5: ATA6561: VIO
               ATA6560: NSIL (the VIO line and the VCC line are internally connected)
```

Question is: given VIO and VCC are *internally connected* in 5V-only versions, can I test continuity between VIO pin and VCC pin to be sure that chip is a 5v-only version and viceversa, knowing a tranceiver is 3V-5V IO compatible if no continuity is found?

This way a simple test with a DMM can help distinguish the chips without even powering them.

EDIT: Ooops, ater Jeroen3 answer I now realize that my question is about logic and not electronic, in addition to being impossible, I should have tought a little more about the problem before asking, thank you. I still wonder if there is a wat to tell a TJA1051T/3 from a TJA1051T/E without reading the markings, but I understand this is a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question is: given VIO and VCC are internally connected in 5V-only versions, can I test continuity between VIO pin and VCC pin to be sure that chip is a 5v-only version and viceversa, knowing a tranceiver is 3V-5V IO compatible if no continuity is found?

No. Since when you have Vio it isn't connected to Vcc. And when you don't have Vio it is ENable or n.c.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the most common SOIC-8 packages, then:

No, isn't an universal method because pin 5 isn't standardized - there's nothing called "VIO" universally. You just happened to come across two similar parts.

On one of the most commonly used parts, MCP2551, which is 5V only, pin 5 is a reference voltage output defined as Vdd/2. On some other parts pin 5 is used for slope control. On other parts it is used for split termination. On other parts it is used for loopback mode and so on.

You have to read the datasheet to tell what pin 5 does and how it works.